# Who's the largest Marvel super-hero?

Tags: marvel, comics, super-hero

Some super-heroes can grow to be quite large, such as Giant-Man and Goliath, but which hero (size-changing included), is the biggest ever seen? No villains, please, I don't care about Galactus.

Comment: Are you talking about height, width, bicep diameter? What about shape-shifters? You should probably create a set of rules for what we can define as largest.

Comment: @edlothiad maybe you should VTC as unclear if you think so, like on the similar question.

Comment: Yours is far clearer in its initial state than the other question was, I’ve understood what you’re looking for, mostly, (especially with your examples) and left s comment to help you to clarify the request a bit better to ensure you got better answers. I would also have re-opened the other post, if rand hadn’t got there first.

Answer (score 7):

In the Marvel universe, you'd probably struggle to find a being larger than [The Beyonder](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Beyonder_(Earth-616)). In his home universe, he *was* the entire universe.

**Size: Infinite.**
[image]

You might also want to consider [Cloud](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_(Earth-616)). As a sentient nebula, she was definitely on the big side. Later she went on to manifest in [a slightly more conventionally sized form](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/0/08/Cloud_%28Earth-616%29_from_Defenders_Strange_Heroes_Vol_1_1_0001.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/206?cb=20161123162929).

**Size: 3+ AU**
[image]

---

As an aside, within the ***DC*** universe we have Mogo the sentient planet. He's a member of the Green Lantern Corp. Not quite universe-sized, but still pretty chunky.

**Size: Planet-sized.**
[image]

Comment: Still smaller than Marvin though ;) "Here I am, brain the size of a planet".

Comment: still arbitrary as to size - just ask Pluto

Comment: "worlds are colliding!!"

Comment: Is the Beyonder really a "super hero?"

Comment: @RogueJedi - Yes. For a time he acted as Strange's semi-sidekick. In Secret Wars II (#6) he decided to destroy Death in order to protect humanity, etc.

Comment: By that token, Thanos is a hero. He's assisted in saving Earth from threats (*INFINITY ABYSS*), and teamed with Warlock to defeat the Magus (*WARLOCK* 9-11). For that matter, thanks to the Ultimates, Galactus is now restoring life to worlds he once destroyed, and saved the Ultimates (*ULTIMATES* (2016) 1-6).

Comment: I don't think Beyonder should count either. He isn't a superhero by any means. The question asked "no villians please, no Galactus" and the Beyonder definitely fits in that category more than the "superhero" category. And his size in his home universe should not count because we don't know what that means anyway.

Comment: @JDoe - He consciously decides to become an actual superhero. That's good enough for me, even if he's been a bit of a meanie before that.

Comment: @Valorum After which he decides to try to destroy the universe again. A superhero is dedicated to saving lives, protecting the public, fighting supervillians, etc, and the Beyonder is not. He only dabbled in being a superhero before rejecting it when it didn't suit him.

Comment: @JDoe - You destroy *one universe* and all of a sudden everyone's pointing fingers and bandying around words like "supervillain". Oy vey.

Comment: In _his_ universe, the Beyonder was the universe, but... Where's the evidence that it matches up with the main universe and isn't say... small enough to fit on [Orion's Belt](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/P7ojSW5pODk/maxresdefault.jpg)